# Setting uniform <input type="file"> width in all browsers

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

What combination of CSS or attributes are needed?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

- Hide the actual control
- Made a DIV with the controls and styling you want on top of it

The button is not a standard HTML control.

See: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Comment: so there's no way to achieve this using the native control itself?

Comment: There is absolutely no need to use opacity - you can simply delegate the click on a display:none element - much simpler and you don't have to take the (varying) input size into account.

Comment: Browsers don't allow to delegate clicks on file input as a security feature. So, we need the opacity for the hack

Answer (score 22):

what's wrong with

```
<input type="file" size="50" .... />
```

?
Will look same except safari on mac i guess (on mac, all upload controls looks different, on all browsers)

Comment: input-width does nothing. You may be thinking of input-size, which does change the width, but not in units that you can standardise across browsers.

Comment: This works...it handles firefox..while CSS width propery handles Chrome, IE, and Safari

Comment: If you want to set a more exact size, could use visibility hidden while binary search for the desired size using javascript...!  I doubt it's worth it, but I would prefer this rather than hiding the actual control.

Comment: W3C fails to validate attribute `size`, because it only allowed on `text, search, url, tel, e-mail, or password` type of fields.

Comment: a "file" input looks and smells like an "text" input, so i wonder whats the point of non-validation, really. Yes i know that doesnt act like a "text" but still takes characters and is a box in a pretty same way...

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the quirksmode tutorial, here's another good resource:
http://www.shauninman.com/archive/2007/09/10/styling_file_inputs_with_css_and_the_dom

If you're hiding the actual control, remember that it is very important to set the opacity of the control to zero, and not actually use `visibility: hidden`. Doing that will actually hide the element, disabling the click action.

Also, if you're covering up the control with a graphic button, do be aware that in some browsers (Firefox and IE, I believe), you will not be able to change the cursor type to a hand when it's over the text-input part of the file control (it will always default to the input or the regular non-link pointer). And yes, I've tried using `cursor: pointer` (and `cursor: hand`).

Personally, I've struggled with customized upload boxes, and there is no silver bullet for getting their appearance or customization perfect. (especially concerning the behavior of the cursor, as I consider that a UI deal-breaker). At the end of the day, I think it's just easier to  accept that different browsers will render the control differently, and that's just how it is.