# How can I style a file input field in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, forms, file

I am currently doing the front end for a site with looooads of forms, all styled up and looking pretty in IE, but I've just noticed that in Firefox the file input fields aren't responding to any of my styles, all the other types of input fields are fine. I've checked it in Firebug and its associating the correct styles to it, but not changing how it looks.

If this isn't a complete brain fart on my behalf, then is this a known issue in Firefox? And if so, how have I never noticed it before?

Here is a sample of the code.

CSS:

```
form.CollateralForm input,
form.CollateralForm textarea
{
    width:300px;
    font-size:1em;
    border: solid 1px #979797;
    font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form method="bla" action="blah" class="CollateralForm">
   <input type="file" name="descriptionFileUpload" id="descriptionFileUpload" />
</form>
```

I've also tried applying a class to it but that doesn't work either.

Comment: This question is a duplicate. See: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269582/setting-uniform-input-typefile-width-in-all-browsers#269602](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/269582/setting-uniform-input-typefile-width-in-all-browsers#269602)

Answer (score 42):

Many of the answers above are quite old. **In 2013 a much simpler solution exists**: nearly all current browsers...

- Chrome
- IE
- Safari
- Firefox with a few-line fix

pass through click events from labels. Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/rvCBX/7/

- Style the `<label>` however you you would like your file upload to be.
- Set `for="someid"` attribute on the label
- Create a `<input id="someid">` element, that's hidden.

Clicking the label will passthrough the event to the fileupload in Chrome, IE, and Safari.

[Firefox requires a very small workaround, which is detailed in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742278/workaround-for-file-input-label-click-firefox).

Comment: @mikemaccana : can i edit css as i want? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/prashantptapase/rvCBX/200/) something like this.. i tried but height, width etc not changing.

Comment: @Prashant Yep, you need to set `display: block` in your example http://jsfiddle.net/prashantptapase/rvCBX/200/

Comment: nice example thanks. If you replace the visibility:hidden with display:none; than it won't effect your style

Answer (score 4):

Firefox can be hacked using the HTML input size attribute:
size="40"
 while using a css width to control the full width of the field + button in layout

Comment: is this still valid? Trying this on Firefox 51.0.1 on Mac does not seem to solve the issue...

Comment: Around Firefox 36, it began following the CSS declarations and at the same time, ignoring the size attribute.

Answer (score 3):

Let's say you have your input:

```
<input style="display:none" id="js-choose-file" type="file">
```

Create a fake button using jQuery.

```
<a id="js-choose-computer" href="javascript:void(0);">From Computer</a>
```

Style the above button any way you like. Then:

```
$("#js-choose-computer").on("click", function() {
  $("#js-choose-file").click();
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Firefox 82, hacks are no longer necessary, per the [::file-selector-button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::file-selector-button) pseudo selector. Current versions of Webkit/Blink browsers (Chrome, Edge, Safari, Opera) don't support it at the moment, but it can be dealt with using the `::-webkit-file-upload-button` non-standard pseudo-class.

This way, your HTML can be kept semantic, and no hacks are needed.

Example code from MDN reference above:

HTML

```
<form>
  <label for="fileUpload">Upload file</label>
  <input type="file" id="fileUpload">
</form>
```

CSS

```
input[type=file]::file-selector-button {
  border: 2px solid #6c5ce7;
  padding: .2em .4em;
  border-radius: .2em;
  background-color: #a29bfe;
  transition: 1s;
}
 
input[type=file]::file-selector-button:hover {
  background-color: #81ecec;
  border: 2px solid #00cec9;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Customformsjs pluggin address this issue on its File module class.
http://customformsjs.com/doc/File.html

http://customformsjs.com/doc/File.js.html

Basicaly it make possible to kind to style File input fields with some restrictions. It work by wrapping it in a container and making it transparent so your click on it. The demo page shows it in action

Answer (score -5):

Use cheat code ( # ) infront of the attribute of css class
say:

```
form.CollateralForm input,
form.CollateralForm textarea
{
    width:300px;  //for firefox
    #width:200px; //for IE7
    _width:100px; //for IE6
    font-size:1em;
    border: solid 1px #979797;
    font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
}
```

Comment: actually, the underscore hack is for IE6.

Comment: i dont see how this will help, the issue is with firefox not responding to any styling for file input fields, its not like its a cross-browser styling issue