# Why this css is not working on Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, input-type-file

I am trying to change the style of my input type file. The follow CSS is working good on Chrome and Opera but not on Mozilla Firefox.

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" />
```

**CSS**

```
.custom-file-input::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.custom-file-input::before {
  content: 'UPLOAD';
  display: inline-block;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, black, red);
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
  outline: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 10pt;
 color:#fff;
}
.custom-file-input:hover::before {
  border-color: #fff;
}
.custom-file-input:active::before {
color:#666;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, bclack, red);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Rameshpardhi/3agapfw3/

I also changed my style to this:

```
.custom-file-input::-moz-file-upload-button {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.custom-file-input::before {
  content: 'UPLOAD';
  display: inline-block;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, black, red);
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px;
  outline: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 10pt;
 color:#fff;
}
.custom-file-input:hover::before {
  border-color: #fff;
}
.custom-file-input:active::before {
color:#666;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, bclack, red);
}
```

But still its not working. I want to know that why this css is not working on Mozzila?

Comment: try to put -moz- in front of property like this : -moz-linear-gradient(top, bclack, red);

Comment: Explain what is going wrong and what should happen

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I style a file input field in Firefox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/352467/how-can-i-style-a-file-input-field-in-firefox)

Comment: There isn't a firefox verion of `-webkit-file-upload-button`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference/Mozilla_Extensions

Comment: I dont know if its duplicate or not, but I am not asking for how to style input type file, what I am asking is why this css is not working on mozilla?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's what you expect, but there is a cross-browser version of your button which use the `<label>` trick.
Feel free to tweak the CSS (click on 'view compiled' if you don't use SASS).

http://codepen.io/mbrillaud/pen/LVEgBy

Comment: Is there any way to do this with css only?

Comment: You need JS to get the value of the input since the input is hidden. The button still work without it but you won't see which file you have selected anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the `-webkit-` declarations? That's just for Chrome and Opera. Either double them and replace them with `-moz-` or remove them altogether.

Try to run autoprefixer on your code to get the correct code.

**Note:** The recommended structure for you would be to have a label around the input field and style that.

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla has no equivalent for the vendor prefixed `::-webkit-form-upload-button`. It’s proprietary (i.e. non-standard) and is only supported in Webkit & Chromium-based browsers.

You can get relative parity in IE: https://www.tjvantoll.com/2013/04/15/list-of-pseudo-elements-to-style-form-controls/#input_file